# Where em datatables com codeigniter

Tags: banco-de-dados, codeigniter, jquery-datatables, where

Eu tenho um código que desenha uma tabela conforme os dados no banco de dados. EX: se ela tem um cliente cadastrado ela vai fazer a tabela com apenas uma linha, se ele não tiver ninguém cadastrado, não vai aparecer nenhuma tabela.
Nesse código também, tenho um filtro (tabletools) que quando você digita qualquer coisa ele confere se existe na tabela. No meu model, preciso colocar um WHERE para aparecer os usuários apenas da empresa que está logada, mas quando coloco isso, o filtro para de funcionar. 
A linha que está dando erro é essa:

```
$this->datatables->where('em.e_id = ' . $this->session->userdata('e_id') . ' AND usr.u_ni = 3 OR em.e_fil = ' . $this->session->userdata('e_id') . ' AND usr.u_ni = 3 ');
```

Comment: Qual o erro que está ocorrendo?

Comment: @Dherik o filtro quando coloco o Where no código ele não funciona, ele filtra mas não aparece o resultado da filtragem na View

Answer (score 1):

confere se os dados da session estão chegando corretamente até a model, da um echo na sessão dentro da model caso os dados retornem certo acredito que seu problema esteja na concatenação, procure user aspas duplas em strings com variáveis juntas ex:

`$this->datatables->where("em.e_id = {$this->session->userdata('e_id')} AND usr.u_ni = 3 OR em.e_fil = {$this->session->userdata('e_id')} AND usr.u_ni = 3");`